# How to delete an element of a vector through a getter function?

Tags: c++, singleton, sdl, state-machine

I am new to C++ and I am working on a game that is using a Singleton design pattern and various state machines.Currently I have most of my games update information within my Engine class update function and I need to move the majority of code over into the Update function in my gamestate class.

Some of the code I need to move manages and deletes enemies in my enemy vector as seen below.      Since I am accessing some of these vectors outside of the class I am using the getter function below. I am trying to delete my enemies if they travel off the screen.This compiles however when an enemy travels off the screen the following Unhandled exception is thrown:
_Mylast was 0xDDDDDDE5. Any help that can be provided is really appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)m_vEnemies.size(); i++)
    {
        m_vEnemies[i]->Update(); 
        if (m_vEnemies[i]->GetDstP()->x < -56)
        {
            delete m_vEnemies[i];
            m_vEnemies[i] = nullptr;

        }
    }
```

```
vector<Enemy*> Engine::getEnemies()
{
    return m_vEnemies;
}
for (int i = 0; i < (int)Engine::Instance().getEnemies().size(); i++)
    {
        Engine::Instance().getEnemies()[i]->Update(); 
        if (Engine::Instance().getEnemies()[i]->GetDstP()->x < -56)
        {
            delete Engine::Instance().getEnemies()[i];
            Engine::Instance().getEnemies()[i] = nullptr;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Beware that when you delete this element and set it to `nullptr` that the next time you iterate over your `vector` you need to ensure you handle elements of `m_vEnemies` being `nullptr` (which you are not currently doing).

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're deleting the object pointed to by `m_vEnemies[i]` and setting `m_vEnemies[i]` to `nullptr`, but the next time you iterate through the array, that `nullptr` is still there and you'll try to dereference it. You also need to `erase` the item from the vector. Items are erased from vectors by using iterators.

However, you can't just iterate through a vector using standard `for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)` semantics and erase the item in the middle of the loop, because erasing an item from a `vector` invalidates its iterators.

The trick is to get in iterator to the item you're removing using

```
std::vector<T *>::iterator erase_iterator = v.begin() + i;
```

which you can then use to remove the item from the `vector` after appropriately deleting it.

When you find an item to delete you:

1. `delete` the allocated memory
2. Decrement your loop variable. On the next loop iteration, you want to check the new item that occupies this same memory address
3. Acquire an iterator of the appropriate type that identifies the current item
4. Call `std::vector::erase(iterator)` to erase the item from the vector.

Not that this causes a reshifting of all pointers in the vector, since items are stored in an array contiguously.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


void print_container_info(std::vector<int *>& container)
{
    std::cout << "Container size: " << container.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Container contents: ";
    for (auto& item : container)
    {
        std::cout << *item << " ";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<int*> p_int_vec = { new int(3), new int(1), new int(2), new int(2), new int(3), new int(3), new int(2) };
    print_container_info(p_int_vec);
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Removing all elements equal to 2 using for loop\n";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < p_int_vec.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (*p_int_vec[i] == 2)
        {
            auto erase_iterator = p_int_vec.begin() + i;
            delete p_int_vec[i];
            p_int_vec.erase(erase_iterator); //no need to set to nullptr, we're removing it from the container
            --i; // must decrement
        }
    }
    print_container_info(p_int_vec);
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}
```

You could also include the `algorithm` library, and use the `std::remove_if` function. `remove_if` applies a predicate on each item of the container, and moves the item to the end of the container (potentially invalidating its data) if a criteria is met. Since the pointer may be invalidated after moving it to the end of the container, we need to `delete` it before the move (i.e., before we return true from the functor).

Then, the container contains all valid elements at the start of the vector, with order preserved, and all invalidated elements at the end. `remove_if` returns an iterator to the start of the range where the invalidated elements start. After calling `remove_if`, you should call `std::erase` on the range between this dummy-start iterator and the end of the container.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void print_container_info(std::vector<int *>& container)
{
    std::cout << "Container size: " << container.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Container contents: ";
    for (auto& item : container)
    {
        std::cout << *item << " ";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<int*> p_int_vec = { new int(3), new int(1), new int(2), new int(2), new int(3), new int(3), new int(2) };
    print_container_info(p_int_vec);
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Removing all elements equal to 2 using for loop\n";
    auto dummy_begin = std::remove_if(p_int_vec.begin(), p_int_vec.end(),
        [](int* p_int) {
            if (*p_int == 2)
            {
                delete p_int;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    p_int_vec.erase(dummy_begin, p_int_vec.end());
    print_container_info(p_int_vec);
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much for all the information! I tried your first suggestion howeverI keep getting an error saying my vector erase iterator is outside range. The code I wrote from your help is  if 
(Engine::Instance().getEnemies()[i]->GetDstP()->x <=-56)
  {
   auto erase_iterator = Engine::Instance().getEnemies().begin() + i;
   delete Engine::Instance().getEnemies()[i];
   Engine::Instance().getEnemies().erase(erase_iterator+i); //no need to set to nullptr, we're removing it from the container
   --i; // must decrement
  }

Comment: @eric The iterator that describes the element you want to delete is `x.begin() + i`, not `x.begin() + i + i`. You're adding `i` twice, which has the potential to go outside bounds at best, and to delete the wrong element silently at worst.

Comment: Hi John, thanks again for the help. I added that as I was still getting the error that the vector erase iterator is outside range without having the extra +1. So with the code 
if (Engine::Instance().getEnemies()[i]->GetDstP()->x <=-56)
  {
   auto erase_iterator = Engine::Instance().getEnemies().begin()+i;
   delete Engine::Instance().getEnemies()[i];
   Engine::Instance().getEnemies().erase(erase_iterator); //no need to set to nullptr, we're removing it from the container
   
   --i;
    // must decrement
  } I still get the same error message

Comment: What does your for loop look like?

Comment: My for loops looks like this:
for (int i = 0; i < (int)Engine::Instance().getEnemies().size(); i++) {}
My enemies get generated on a timer if that makes a difference

Comment: Your `getEnemies` function should return a reference to `m_vEnemies`. Right now it's copying the vector. You're able to call `delete` on the pointer just fine, because a copy of a pointer still dereferences to the correct location, but when you try to `erase` it from the vector, you're only erasing from the copy, not from the original. You should also see some speedup in your code since you're not copying the vector anymore every time you call `getEnemies()`. Change the function signature to `std::vector<Enemy *>& Engine::getEnemies()`

Comment: Awesome that workes thank you so much I really appreciate it!!!!!!